# C++ Boolean problem (comparison between two arrays)

Tags: c++

I have a problem to do. I already did some part of it, however I stuck and don't know exactly what to do next.

The question: " You are given two arrays of ints, named A and B. One contains AMAXELEMENTS and the other contains BMAXELEMENTS. Write a Boolean-valued function that returns true if there is at least one point in A that is the same as a point in B, and false if there is no match between two arrays. "

The two arrays are made up by me, I think if I know how to compare two arrays I will be fine, and I will be able to finish my problem.

This is what I have so far (I changed AMAXELEMENTS to AMAX, and BMAXELEMENTS to BMAX):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int AMAX = 5, BMAX = 6;
    int i;
    bool c1 = true, c2 = false;
    int A[AMAX] = { 2, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    int B[BMAX] = { 9, 12, 32, 43, 23, 11 };

    for (i = 0; i < BMAX; i++)
        if (B[i] == A[i])       //  <---- I think this part has to look
                                //        different, but I can't figure it out.
            cout << c1 << endl;
        else
            cout << c2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to return true if there is an `i` such that `A[i] == B[i]` or if there is an `i, j` such that `A[i] == B[j]`?

Comment: The more serious problem here is, that you're going over the bounds of array A! BMAX is higher than AMAX, and your loop will end up checking memory behind the array A that isn't even allocated to it!

Comment: return true if there is "i" such A[i]==B[i]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like homework so I'm not going to feed you the answer.  But I will point out some basic issues.

First off, you should be trying to define a function that returns true/false:

```
bool has_identical_value(int A[], size_t A_MAX, int B[], size_t B_MAX)
{
    bool answer = false;

    ... your homework goes here ...

    return answer;
}
```

Second is to make sure you never reference an `A[i]` where `i >= A_MAX` and you never reference `B[j]` where `j >= B_MAX`.

Comment: It's actually a sample exam problem, I am trying to do it as my practice.

Answer (score 2):

You should loop over the 2 arrays, not over 1 array to compare. Else you will compare 2 with 9, 4 with 12 etc

Here some pointing in the right direction:

```
for(i=0;i<BMAX;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<AMAX;j++)
    {
        if (B[i]==A[j])
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You should wrap it in a function as your question states.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to write a function. Then learn about functions because it looks like currently you have no clue what function is.

And here's the hint, what your loop is doing wrong?

```
for(i=0;i<BMAX;i++)
   if (B[i]==A[i]) //A[BMAX - 1]???
```

Comment: No need for sarcasm (I did not ding you)

Comment: I just saw the phrase "you have no clue" as being a little sarcastic.

Comment: @Romain Hippeau: it wasn't my intention to be sarcastic, rather a bit harsh (I guess you know why).

Comment: So I did some studying, and this is how I end up:
#include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

    int main (){
   
      const int SIZE=10;
      int A[]={4,32,9,7,14,12,13,17,19,18};
   
      double sum, avg, max;
      int i;
      max=A[0];
      for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
         sum+=A[i];
      
       if(A[i]>max){ max=A[i];}
   }
   
   
     avg=sum/10;
   
   if(2*avg<=max)
   cout<<"OUTLIER= "<<max<<endl;
   
   else
   cout<<"OK"<<endl;  
   
      return 0;
   
   }

Answer (score 0):

MY answer again... after couple of hours of working with this :)
Thanks for help!

## include

using namespace std;

bool myBool(int, int, int[], int[]);

```
int main(){

  const int SIZEA=5;
  const int SIZEB=4;
 int A[]={54,65,76,67,4};
  int B[]={23,435,67,5};

  if (myBool(SIZEA, SIZEB,A,B))
     cout<<"TRUE"<<endl;
  
  else
     cout<<"FALSE"<<endl;
  return 0;
```

}

```
bool myBool(int AMAXELEMENTS, int BMAXELEMENTS, int A[], int B[]){
  int i,j;

  for(i=0;i<AMAXELEMENTS;i++){
     for(j=0;j<BMAXELEMENTS;j++){
        if(A[i]==B[j])
           return true;       
     }
  } 
  return false;
```

}